# VBScript How can I Format Date?

Tags: date, vbscript

I want the date to look like **MM-DD-YYYY** instead of **MM/DD/YYYY**.

Comment: Be aware that in some systems, slashes are assumed to be American format (m/d/y) and dashes are assumed to be Euro format (d-m-y).  So in certain cases switching an American style date to dashes may cause problems, or at least confusion

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yy and time if specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday, monthname, year
2 = vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yy
3 = vbLongTime - Returns time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
4 = vbShortTime - Return time: hh:mm


d=CDate("2010-02-16 13:45")
document.write(FormatDateTime(d) & "<br />")
document.write(FormatDateTime(d,1) & "<br />")
document.write(FormatDateTime(d,2) & "<br />")
document.write(FormatDateTime(d,3) & "<br />")
document.write(FormatDateTime(d,4) & "<br />")
```

If you want to use another format you will have to create your own function and parse Month, Year, Day, etc and put them together in your preferred format.

```
Function myDateFormat(myDate)
    d = TwoDigits(Day(myDate))
    m = TwoDigits(Month(myDate))    
    y = Year(myDate)
    myDateFormat= m & "-" & d & "-" & y
End Function

Function TwoDigits(num)
    If(Len(num)=1) Then
        TwoDigits="0"&num
    Else
        TwoDigits=num
    End If
End Function
```

edit: added function to format day and month as `0n` if value is less than `10`.

Comment: A lot of work for what `Right(“00” & Day(myDate), 2)` already does.

Comment: vbShortDate is actually m/d/yyyy from my testing.

Answer (score 28):

Suggest calling 'Now' only once in the function to guard against the minute, or even the day, changing during the execution of the function.

Thus:

```
Function timeStamp()
    Dim t 
    t = Now
    timeStamp = Year(t) & "-" & _
    Right("0" & Month(t),2)  & "-" & _
    Right("0" & Day(t),2)  & "_" & _  
    Right("0" & Hour(t),2) & _
    Right("0" & Minute(t),2) '    '& _    Right("0" & Second(t),2) 
End Function
```

Comment: Another way to pad the month or day with a 0 is the following:

`Right(Month(Now)+100,2)`

Answer (score 9):

The output of FormatDateTime depends on configuration in Regional Settings in Control Panel. So in other countries FormatDateTime(d, 2) may for example return yyyy-MM-dd.

If you want your output to be "culture invariant", use myDateFormat() from stian.net's solution. If you just don't like slashes in dates and you don't care about date format in other countries, you can just use

```
Replace(FormatDateTime(d,2),"/","-")
```

Comment: Seems like you're saying FormatDateTime (stian.net's solution) both is and isn't culture-invariant... ? Confused...

Answer (score 7):

'for unique file names I use

```
Dim ts, logfile, thisScript

thisScript = LEFT(Wscript.ScriptName,LEN(Wscript.ScriptName)-4) ' assuming .vbs extension

ts = timeStamp
logfile = thisScript & "_" & ts

' ======
Function timeStamp() 
    timeStamp = Year(Now) & "-" & _
    Right("0" & Month(Now),2)  & "-" & _
    Right("0" & Day(Now),2)  & "_" & _  
    Right("0" & Hour(Now),2) & _
    Right("0" & Minute(Now),2) '    '& _    Right("0" & Second(Now),2) 
End Function
' ======
```

Answer (score 3):

This snippet also solve this question with [datePart function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529.aspx). I've also used the `right()` trick to perform a `rpad(x,2,"0")`.

```
option explicit

Wscript.Echo "Today is " & myDate(now)

' date formatted as your request
Function myDate(dt)
    dim d,m,y, sep
    sep = "-"
    ' right(..) here works as rpad(x,2,"0")
    d = right("0" & datePart("d",dt),2)
    m = right("0" & datePart("m",dt),2)
    y = datePart("yyyy",dt)
    myDate= m & sep & d & sep & y
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might still need this in the future. My answer is very similar to qaweb, just a lot less intimidating. There seems to be no cool automatic simple function to formate date in VBS. So you'll have to do it manually. I took the different components of the date and concatenated them together.

```
Dim timeStamp
timeStamp = Month(Date)&"-"&Day(Date)&"-"&Year(Date)
run = msgbox(timeStamp)
```

Which will result in `11-22-2019` (depending on the current date)

Answer (score -1):

Although answer is provided I found simpler solution:

Date:

```
01/20/2017
```

By doing replace

```
CurrentDate = replace(date, "/", "-")
```

It will output:

```
01-20-2017
```

Comment: Depending on the system's locale settings, this might not result in MM-DD-YYYY