# Need to convert 3 letter month code to two letter month code python

Tags: python

I am trying to get a date formatted, i.e., from `Jan` to `JA`, `Feb` to `FE`. I have a dictionary built to do this, however my code only works randomly, e.g., sometimes every 4 times, sometimes every 24 times. I am new to Python, and I can't make sense of this. The output from the below code is `16Jun28` most of the time, but correctly `16JN28` sometimes.

```
import datetime
month_code = {'Jan': 'JA', 
      'Feb': 'FE', 
      'Mar': 'MR', 
      'Apr': 'AL', 
      'May': 'MA', 
      'Jun': 'JN', 
      'Jul': 'JL', 
      'Aug': 'AU', 
      'Sep': 'SE', 
      'Oct': 'OC', 
      'Nov': 'NO', 
      'Dec': 'DE'}

today = datetime.datetime.now()
DD = datetime.timedelta(days=90)    
use_by = today + DD
use_by_str = use_by.strftime("%y-%b-%d")

def label_function():
    month = use_by.strftime("%b")
    year = use_by.strftime("%y")
    day = use_by.strftime("%d")
    return year + month + day

line = label_function()

for k, v in month_code.items():
    Result = line.replace(k, v)
print(Result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating through your dictionary to replace your 3 char month name to 2 char, but you're always placing the result in a different variable, and not mutating `line` itself.

What you'd be looking for would be

```
for k, v in month_code.items():
    line = line.replace(k, v)
```

As an aside, why not have your `label_function` return a tuple of your date string, and then you only need to alter 1 value with 1 lookup instead.

```
def label_function():
    month = use_by.strftime('%b')
    year = use_by.strftime('%y')
    day = use_by.strftime('%d')
    return year, month, day

year, month, day = label_function()
result = year + month_code[month] + day
```

Comment: Both solutions worked perfectly.  The aside answer is the one I will go with!  In the grand scheme of things I was not thinking that 12 iterations was that big of a deal...I appreciate the help!

Comment: This might get me thrown out of the forum, but any ideas on how to convert to VBScript?

Comment: That won't get you thrown out of the forum ;) You can take a look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003923/vbscript-how-can-i-format-date there for an idea on where to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Christian has already shown a better way to implement what you need. I'll try to explain the bug.

It works randomly because of a logic error in your code combined with the random ordering of dictionaries.

You have two variables, `line` and `Result`. Suppose `line` is '16Feb28'. Your code

- takes `line`, tries to replace Jan with JA, and puts the result (unchanged) into `Result`.
- Then it takes `line`, tries to replace Feb with FE, and puts the result (16FE28) into `Result`.
- Then it takes `line` (16Feb28), tries to replace Mar with MR, and puts the result (16Feb28) into `Result`.
- and so on. Can you see the problem now?
- Finally it takes `line` (16Feb28), tries to replace Dec with DE, and puts the result (16Feb28) into `Result`.

The reason that it *sometimes* works is that in reality dictionaries are not iterated in the order in which you write them in the source code, but in a random one, so the matching entry Feb->FE sometimes happens to be the last one.

Why is the order random? See [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Is there a reasoning behind the dict is randomly ordered?  The explanation you provided makes perfect sense otherwise.