# Server Date/Time Settings print out American Format

Tags: vb.net, windows, date, datetime

I have a windows server running an Application (Metastorm) written in VB Script that prints out a log file in american date format. I want it to be in U.K format (DD/MM/YYYY).

I don't want to format the date in the script, I want to know what is causing this. It isn't just logging that is an issue, this is causing us many other issues behind the scenes.

I am certain it uses the server settings to get the date/time, but the server settings show U.K Format

**Script that writes Log File** (Pretty standard, works on all other servers)

```
 ...
 ework.WriteText now() & " - " & cStr(p_Data),OutputLogPath & thisFileName
```

**Log File (written on the 13th April 2017)**

```
4/13/2017 3:32:38 PM - ******** End ValidateForm ********
4/13/2017 3:32:38 PM - thislineTotalExVat = 50
4/13/2017 3:32:38 PM - thisTaxRate = 20
4/13/2017 3:32:38 PM - thisLineTotal = 60
4/13/2017 3:32:38 PM - eworknumDiscountPercentage = 0
```

Printing out the current datetime through VB Script is showing as American Format.

**I've changed all I can find in the windows server settings:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by UK format? you mean include pm and am or you mean have day before month or you mean UK timezone

Comment: Is this vb.net or vbScript? Tag your question correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript How can I Format Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003923/vbscript-how-can-i-format-date)

Comment: @Pikoh No I don't want to format the date, I want to know what is happening behind the scenes here.

Comment: Well,use [`GetLocale`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d457t70w(v=vs.84).aspx) to see what locale is it getting

Comment: Anyway, i would never trust system settings for handling dates if the format might be a problem. Format it to your needs or at least set the locale

Comment: @rednaxela I know this is an old question but have you set your date format in `eUserOptions.js` (located in C:\Program Files\Metastorm BPM\Web\ie\jscripts on the server)?